# Why RSA-sig authentication VPN need its own private key?

Tags: rsa

In my understanding, RSA-sig authentication only requires its own Public Key so that the peer authenticates it using Root CA's public key. But, [strongSwan VPN](https://www.strongswan.org/) configuration requires its own private key. I can't understand it. Am I wrong about RSA-Sig authentication or is strongSwan using RSA encryption?

Comment: Did you asked them?

Comment: Is the private key used in RSA-sig authentication or only Public key?

Comment: RSA can be used for both encryption and signatures with proper padding schemes. It is usual to use different keys ( modulus and public and private key exponenets) for different purpsoses.

Comment: Could you explain how RSA-sig authentication method work in the authentication process like IKE? Only check the authenticity of a public key using trusted CA?

Comment: Could you edit your question for your actual question?

Answer (score 1):

> In my understanding, RSA-sig authentication only requires its own Public Key so that the peer authenticates it using Root CA's public key.

No, that is not how PKI (Public Key Infrastructure) works.  Yes, the CA does issue a certificate (authenticated by the root CA's public key), however the certificate just says "this specific public key corresponds to a private key owned by themasterplan".

That is, a certificate is a way to bind a public key (which is a series of random-looking bits) to an identity (a label that is meaningful to the reader of the certificate); it is one way to solve the question "how do we know that this particular public key is from who we want to talk to".

So, to meaningfully authenticate yourself with a certificate, you need your own private key (so that the certificate can refer to your public key); that is the public/private key that StrongSwan requires.

And, a StrongSwan service authenticates itself by sending its certificate (so that the peer knows and can verify the public key), as well as a signature (to prove that the StrongSwan implementation has the private key that the certificate refers to).

Comment: So, ROOT CA is just for the trusting the strongswan's certificate and actual authentication process is performed by storngswan's private  and public key, which means sign and verify is used in peer authentication? Then.hat data ( message )  is used in private key signing..? I'm new to crypto and IKE. and also I'm not good at English enough to exactly understand the RFC and documents. sorry

Comment: A hash of any random message is encrypted with the private key, and the receiver verifies the hash by decrypting it with the sender's public key. In this process, it verifies that the ID of the certificate, such as the common name or SAN, matches the peer's IP or FQDN, and authenticates the peer. Here, the role of ROOT CA certificate is simply to trust the sender's public key. Is that right?

Comment: @themasterplan: the role of the ROOT CA certificate is to provide a proof (assuming you trust the CA) that the sender's public key corresponds to the identity (common name or FQDN, generally not peer IP).